# Delete user in AAD B2C using Active directory graph client

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have used below code to delete a user from Azure active directory B2C.

```cs
Uri servicePointUri = new Uri("https://graph.windows.net");

Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, "xxxx.onmicrosoft.com");

var activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await GetAccessToken());

var myUser = new Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User()
                {
                    ObjectId = "63ca9c1d-2bd0-4a6b-8bf6-b850b16ed50b"
                };

await myUser.DeleteAsync();
```

But I have ended up with exception message "Not Initialized".

Can some one tell me what is the issue with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have to retrieve the user you want to delete first. E. g.:

```
var user = await Client.Users.Where(u => u.ObjectId.Equals("63ca9c1d-2bd0-4a6b-8bf6-b850b16ed50b"))).ExecuteSingleAsync();
await user.DeleteAsync();
```

Comment: Code is works but got exception related to privilege not sufficient.

Comment: But the GetAccessToken() method is getting called twice, 1. while create the activeDirectoryClient 2. While executing the code DeleteAsync. Is that normal behavior and same token can be reused?

Comment: You probably lack permissions. See: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_delete

Comment: the link you have posted is pointing to Microsoft Graph api (https://graph.microsoft.com) but I'm using AAD graph api "https://graph.windows.net"

Comment: You are right. However, you probably lack permissions :)

Comment: ok :-) Any thought on the second comment, that is GetAccessToken getting called twice. Is that normal behavior?

Comment: Well I think thats normal since the access_token is only valid for a limit time. You could write a local function that returns the token that you retrieved once or introduce a token cache if you need it

Comment: You don't need .Result if you use `await`